# Deploying a Heroku App using Node.js error code H10

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

Hello everyone I thought that deploying my node app on Heroku would be a breeze but it is turning out to be less than easy. After deploying 24 builds I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Running my app using localhost:[port] works fine and has been but on Heroku it isn't awesome.

I notice that when I am using the command `git push heroku master` I see that my node packages are being recreated(?):

```
Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        express@4.14.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/express
remote:        accepts@1.3.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/accepts
remote:        mime-types@2.1.11 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/mime-types
remote:        mime-db@1.23.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/mime-db
remote:        negotiator@0.6.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/negotiator
remote:        array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/array-flatten
remote:        content-disposition@0.5.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/content-disposition
remote:        content-type@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/content-type
remote:        cookie@0.3.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/cookie
remote:        cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/cookie-signature
remote:        debug@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/debug
remote:        ms@0.7.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/ms
remote:        depd@1.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/depd
remote:        encodeurl@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/encodeurl
remote:        escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/escape-html
remote:        etag@1.7.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/etag
remote:        finalhandler@0.5.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/finalhandler
remote:        on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/on-finished
remote:        ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/ee-first
remote:        statuses@1.3.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/statuses
remote:        unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/unpipe
remote:        fresh@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/fresh
remote:        merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/merge-descriptors
remote:        methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/methods
remote:        parseurl@1.3.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/parseurl
remote:        path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/path-to-regexp
remote:        proxy-addr@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/proxy-addr
remote:        forwarded@0.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/forwarded
remote:        ipaddr.js@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/ipaddr.js
remote:        qs@6.2.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/qs
remote:        range-parser@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/range-parser
remote:        send@0.14.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/express/node_modules/send
remote:        destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/destroy
remote:        http-errors@1.5.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/http-errors
remote:        inherits@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/inherits
remote:        setprototypeof@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/setprototypeof
remote:        mime@1.3.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/mime
remote:        serve-static@1.11.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/serve-static
remote:        send@0.14.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/send
remote:        type-is@1.6.13 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/type-is
remote:        media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/media-typer
remote:        utils-merge@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/utils-merge
remote:        vary@1.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/vary
remote:        jade@1.11.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/jade
remote:        character-parser@1.2.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/character-parser
remote:        clean-css@3.4.18 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/clean-css
remote:        commander@2.8.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules/commander
remote:        graceful-readlink@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/graceful-readlink
remote:        source-map@0.4.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/source-map
remote:        amdefine@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/amdefine
remote:        commander@2.6.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/commander
remote:        constantinople@3.0.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/constantinople
remote:        acorn@2.7.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/acorn
remote:        jstransformer@0.0.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/jstransformer
remote:        is-promise@2.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/is-promise
remote:        promise@6.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/promise
remote:        asap@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/asap
remote:        mkdirp@0.5.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/mkdirp
remote:        minimist@0.0.8 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/minimist
remote:        transformers@2.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/transformers
remote:        css@1.0.8 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/css
remote:        css-parse@1.0.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/css-parse
remote:        css-stringify@1.0.5 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/css-stringify
remote:        promise@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/promise
remote:        is-promise@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/is-promise
remote:        uglify-js@2.2.5 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js
remote:        optimist@0.3.7 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/optimist
remote:        wordwrap@0.0.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/wordwrap
remote:        source-map@0.1.43 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/source-map
remote:        uglify-js@2.6.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/uglify-js
remote:        async@0.2.10 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/async
remote:        source-map@0.5.6 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map
remote:        uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify
remote:        yargs@3.10.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/yargs
remote:        camelcase@1.2.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/camelcase
remote:        cliui@2.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/cliui
remote:        center-align@0.1.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/center-align
remote:        align-text@0.1.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/align-text
remote:        kind-of@3.0.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/kind-of
remote:        is-buffer@1.1.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/is-buffer
remote:        longest@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/longest
remote:        repeat-string@1.5.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/repeat-string
remote:        lazy-cache@1.0.4 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/lazy-cache
remote:        right-align@0.1.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/right-align
remote:        wordwrap@0.0.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/wordwrap
remote:        decamelize@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/decamelize
remote:        window-size@0.1.0 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/window-size
remote:        void-elements@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/void-elements
remote:        with@4.0.3 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/with
remote:        acorn@1.2.2 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn
remote:        acorn-globals@1.0.9 /tmp/build_a769e7fce1f5ff3a3dbd69d44125be90/node_modules/acorn-globals
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:
```

I apologize for that huge wall of text but what you're seeing, from what I understand, is that all my node modules in my `node_modules` folder are being recreated for some reason. But after this happens the build is successful and ready to be used.

So when I run the command `heroku ps:scale web=1` I get the message `Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free`. So far so good, but when I actually open my app I get an application error, so I type `heroku logs -n 52` because I've done this so many times I know how many lines are relevant to me. But here is what is given back to me:

```
2016-06-23T23:02:31.826487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-23T23:04:08.293203+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v24 created by mauricecunningham@ymail.com
2016-06-23T23:04:08.293113+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a4025b7 by mauricecunningham@ymail.com
2016-06-23T23:04:08.501758+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-06-23T23:04:08.501767+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-06-23T23:04:08.465484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-23T23:04:12.635495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-06-23T23:04:15.429410+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.429425+00:00 app[web.1]: > abcusd@1.0.0 start /app
2016-06-23T23:04:15.429431+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/app.js
2016-06-23T23:04:15.429432+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639033+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639043+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639043+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639059+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './mock/test.json'
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639057+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639062+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639062+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:4:19)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639064+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.654257+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.4.5
2016-06-23T23:04:15.653958+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-06-23T23:04:15.653512+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
2016-06-23T23:04:15.639065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
2016-06-23T23:04:15.646563+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.655142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656197+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the abcusd package,
2016-06-23T23:04:15.655683+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656034+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the abcusd@1.0.0 start script 'node src/app.js'.
2016-06-23T23:04:15.655527+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! abcusd@1.0.0 start: `node src/app.js`
2016-06-23T23:04:15.655890+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656507+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656352+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656663+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node src/app.js
2016-06-23T23:04:15.656813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-06-23T23:04:15.657050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs abcusd
2016-06-23T23:04:15.655368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-06-23T23:04:15.657292+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.657124+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-23T23:04:15.657430+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls abcusd
2016-06-23T23:04:15.657611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-06-23T23:04:15.660924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T23:04:15.661300+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-23T23:04:15.661148+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-06-23T23:04:16.484660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-23T23:04:16.476664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-23T23:04:24.383512+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abcusd.herokuapp.com request_id=c782e08e-5862-4ae2-89ab-26d2c52aba1b fwd="99.6.116.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-23T23:04:24.784780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abcusd.herokuapp.com request_id=93241ada-ddfa-4356-9d1f-e6809ee8ef6c fwd="99.6.116.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The part that interests me most is this: `Error: Cannot find module './mock/test.json'` that's just a reference to a json file that provides data to my pages when rendered and to my knowledge not a module the same way a node module is considered a module. I think that when the modules are being recreated my json file is being screwed up but that's really just a guess at this point. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

EDIT - including `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "abcusd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "special education website",
  "main": "ABCUSD/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/m00se333/ABCUSD.git"
  },
  "author": "Maurice Cunningham",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/m00se333/ABCUSD/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/m00se333/ABCUSD#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check that mock/test.json reaches heroku and isn't being ignored by git? Also what does the file contain? Maybe double check that all your required module are in your package.json as dependencies.

Comment: See writing `'./mock/test.json'` this as `'/mock/test.json'` without dot.

Comment: @theatlasroom Thanks for responding, I made sure that all my files are being tracked by git, nothing is slipping through the cracks. The path to the file `./mock/test.json` is not a node module however.

@EshwarPrasadYaddanapudi I am going to try that right now again, but I believe that I was fiddling with it and in the process tried your suggestion `/mock/test.json` and I don't think that worked. But I will report back thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. Are you able to post your file/folder structure? If your require path looks ok assuming you're running your app.js from the root

Comment: And also your .gitignore file.

Comment: @theatlasroom I just added my file structure to the post thanks for taking the time to take a look. I also ran a `ls -a` command and I don't have a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Wheres the mock folder located?

Comment: `src/mock/test.json` and my app.js is here: `src/app.js`

Comment: You might need to change your require statement to `require('./src/mock/test.json');` i think heroku would be running from your application root not from inside your `src` dir

Comment: Hey there @theatlasroom I tried `require ("./src/mock/test.json")` and I still get an error `Error: Cannot find module './src/mock/test.JSON'`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your source files is requiring ./mock/test.json but it's not in git and so is not uploaded to heroku.

Module in this instance is node's Module.js which handles require calls. Give the path that's failing this has nothing to do with node_modules.

Comment: Hi @bknights I just checked my github repo and all my files are tracked. But I think that there is something wrong with my `package.json` file. I don't know how to set the default path where the server starts, for example I want to be in the root of my file system so I can accurately reference other files but I don't think I've done that correctly. Would you like to see my `package.json` file?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt. Does your project run locally? If you have a scripts.start in your package.json what happens when you run that command from the root of your project?

Comment: I just edited my question to include my `package.json`. To answer your questions yes my project runs locally using either:
`nodemon src/app.js` -- or -- `node src/app.js`.  The root of my project is `haloApp` on my local machine. I don't know what it becomes when it is deployed on heroku.

Comment: No idea really.  What are the root relative paths to mock/test.json and the file that requires  it?

Comment: `abcusd/src/mock/test.json`

`abcusd/src/app.js`

Comment: Have you got a Procfile? What is in it?

Comment: I don't have a Procfile but I am familiar with the notion. Should I try starting my app with a Procfile instead?

Comment: Yes. Although the documentation indicates the start method from package.json should work just a well. Also you could try: `heroku local web` to see if your issue is repeated there (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

Comment: Alright @bknights I added the Procfile in the latest build and it still didn't work. I am getting the same error where I can't find `/mock/test.json` I ran `heroku local web` and the same thing occurred it seems more and more that my internals are all scrambled. What I mean by that I have a funky root folder and my `app.js` is just incorrectly referencing files.